# No numeric index needed when saving nested attributes of a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Parent model, and a Child model. I'm trying to make a form for creating a Parent and its associated Children at the same time.

In my form, I have a button to "add" a new Child (a Parent can have as many Children as the user defines). When the button is clicked, it adds a hidden field for a Child to the form and sets its Name attribute to some default which will be saved when the form is eventually submitted. I've been doing this by adding a `hidden_field_tag` to the form on the button click event:

```
hidden_field_tag "parent[children_attributes][][name]", "something"
```

Which creates:

```
<input id="children_attributes__name" name="parent[children_attributes][][name]" type="hidden" value="something">
```

This seems to work! But I am concerned for the empty `[]`. I'm not sure what it is or why it works, I just discovered that it does. Is it safe to use?

When I look at form fields created using `fields_for`, I see that it sets an numeric index for that middle array/hash (whatever it is), like so:

```
<input id="children_attributes_0_name" name="parent[children_attributes][0][name]" type="text">
```

Unfortunately, I can't use `fields_for` because I have to add the hidden fields only when the "add" button is clicked.

What's the right approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Your second question "What's the right approach here?"

I always use [Ryan Bate's nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). Sorts all this kind of stuff out for you.

Your First question "Is it safe to use?"

I dont know. If ever i have to do it manually, I make sure that its a unique value in [].

The gem i believe uses a timestamp to keep it unique.